# NSPredicate (== comparison to numeric string) not working

Tags: objective-c, core-data

So here's the deal:

```
// A. Inserting
Item *item = (Item *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSError *error = nil;
[managedObjectContext save:&error];
..
[item setItemID:@"15"];
[managedObjectContext save:&error];
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error); // outputs (null)    

// B. Fetching all records
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Item"];
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
NSArray *allItems = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
NSLog(@"All Items: %@", allItems);
```

Now, this outputs a huge list, containing the previously inserted item:

```
"<Item: 0x7eb7bc0> (entity: Item; id: 0x7eb71c0 <x-coredata://BC6EB71C-47C0-4445-905D-7D42E6FC611B/Item/p2> ; data: {\n    itemID = 15;\n})"
```

So far so good, but I want to check whether this particular item does exist (I know it may sound strange in this context, but it really makes sense here). However, the predicate I'm using fails (and I don't see why):

```
// C. Fetching a single record
NSFetchRequest *singleRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Item"];
singleRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemID == %@", @"15"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:singleRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error); // outputs (null) again
NSLog(@"Results: %@", results); // outputs () ...
```

I don't really understand how to "fix" this.

Here are some other facts:

- Using persistent SQLite store with CoreData (pretty much default configuration, not even relationships, just plain key-value in 3 tables).
- The `itemID`s always are strings
- When reopening the app, the second code block, does return an item (= the item inserted in the previous run). Could it be that `save:` writes to disk asynchronously, and that the `NSPredicate` only filters items wrote to disk?

Part `A` happens in a different method, but on the same thread as `B` and `C`. `C` is directly below `B` and both are placed in the same method.

Comment: so youre saying that section B works all the time (including multiple times), but section C only works after your restart the App?

Comment: Yes, B works all the time, and also returns the new item inserted in section A (still in the same "run"). In the first run this is `#15`, second run `#16`, etc. When in the second run, I can query `#15` in section C, but I cannot query `#16`. Querying all items in section B in the second run, returns both `#15` and `#16`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comparing strings, try this :

```
@"itemID LIKE %@"
```

Have a [read of this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html), the section titled 'String Comparisons"

Comment: Doesn't do the trick either :(. And besides that, it doesn't make sense that `==` does work after restarting the app, searching to the previously inserted `itemID`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Okay got it. I used `@synthesize` instead of `@dynamic` in the particular model's `.m`-file. Didn't know it would be such a big problem .. :)
For some reason, updating the SQLite-database goes wrong when using `@synthesize` ..